# How do you add custom metadata to WooCommerce orders? Specifically a second external order ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on building a custom integration from WooCommerce to our internal ERP. I hooked into the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` so that when an order is placed I send all relevant information to our ERP and the reply is an order ID. This is a different order ID than what is in WooCommerce and I need a way to map the ERP order ID to the WooCommerce order. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried adding custom metadata, but so far that has failed.
`add_metadata( "shop_order", $order->id, "mapics_order", (string) $orderNumber, TRUE );` and am trying to avoid using `wc_add_order_item_meta` since this is not item specific, but for the entire order itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook to update order meta. Please check sample code

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['mapics_order'])
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'mapics_order', esc_attr(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['mapics_order'])));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I stripped it down to just `update_post_meta` which seems to be working fine, but I will need to do some checks to be sure.

Comment: sessions? are they still allowed in php? ;) more seriously, where does exactly the data supposed to get into the session?

Comment: Passing data into a session is easy, and even if its not a perfect answer it gave me the missing piece that I needed to continue my project.